# How to use ASP.NET and JSON to call C# Code

Tags: asp.net, ajax, razor

I am creating a game that I am using ajax and ASP.net to create a two player game. So I am trying to create a couple of buttons for the player to use to "play" a card if it is their turn. I am currently stuck on trying to get the json to call the c# code, but have not been successful yet.

Here is where I'm at:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#slap").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Pages/index/",
            data: {
              //Something goes here
            },
            success: function (result) {
                alert('ok');
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert('There was an error');
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Then in the C# code index.cshtml.cs I have a function like playCard().

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure if razor works like asp.net ajax, but if you're using a script manager, research 'Page Methods'.

Comment: Is this bit of jQuery included in the Razor page?  I don't think you need to reference the Pages directory in your url property.  Maybe try `url: "/index"`

Answer (score 0):

Url format is wrong. It should be like "/controller/action"